# How can I use return values of one function to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

first I am Passing value to setCategory using onClick method.

```
<div class=\"Subcat\">Select Subcategory</div> 
<div class=\"cont5\"> 
<div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Album',this)\" > Music Album </div>
 <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Channel',this)\"> Music Channel </div>
 <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Award',this)\"> Music Award </div>
 <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Chart',this)\"> Music Chart </div>
</div>


function setCategory(category,subcategory)
{
    var category=category;
    var subcategory=subcategory;

    return {category:category,subcategory:subcategory};
};

function saveHouse( ){
    var cat= setCategory();
    var catg=cat.category;
    var subcat= cat.subcategory;

    alert(catg);
    alert(subcat);
};
```

I want to send values of variable `category` and `subcategory` of `setCategory()` function to `saveHouse()` function. But when I try to display values in alert, it shows me values of the both variables are "undefined". Pls check both function and solve my problem. I don't know much about javascript local and global scope. Thank you

Comment: You never pass any values into `setCategory`, as a result the returned object has `undefined` for both `category` and `subcategory`. This is all defined behavior. If you want to assign `category` and `subcategory`, then you must pass an argument to `setCategory` for each one of those.

Comment: Hello, I am passing values to setCategory( ) function after click on div.

Comment: But you're not passing values when you call it from `saveHouse()`.

Comment: <div class=\"Subcat\">Select Subcategory</div>
     <div class=\"cont5\">
  <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Album',this)\" >   Music Album </div>
  <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Channel',this)\">   Music Channel </div>
  <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Award',this)\">   Music Award </div>
  <div class=\"part10\" onClick=\"setCategory('Music','Music Chart',this)\">   Music Chart </div>

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not put in the question. So frustrated.

Comment: @user2668276 Use the "edit" link to put it into the question.

Comment: huhh??? I have no idea what you are intending to do with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setCategory` should put the object in a global variable, not return it as a value.

```
var chosenCategory;
function setCategory(category,subcategory)
{
    chosenCategory = {category:category,subcategory:subcategory};
};

function saveHouse( ){
    if (chosenCategory) {
        var catg = chosenCategory.category;
        var subcat = chosenCategory.subcategory;

        alert(catg);
        alert(subcat);
    } else {
        alert("Please choose a category first");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setCategory without any parameters, so it is correct for you to get undefined when you call alert.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and time user1.

Answer (score 0):

`setCategory` should receive parameters, otherwise `category` and `subcategory` will continue to be undefined.

You could fix this by calling: `var cat = setCategory(<somevalue>, <othervalue>)`.

If you are calling `setCategory()` via an onClick event, `saveHouse()` does not run because it is never called. You may want to rethink your onClick events.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and time Matt.